# How to pass optional<vector<optional<uuid>>> from C++ to Swift?

Tags: c++, ios, swift, objective-c

I have following problem:

I have iOS application with C++ core. Data is bridged through C++<->ObjCpp<->ObjC chain, data structures are later imported in swift from ObjC.

I have optional<vector<optional>> in one of my structures and there is problem with importing it. Vector is converted to NSList, which is populated by data. Because there can't be nil in NSList, I add NSNull to it. If vector isn't optional - I can work with it in Swift, though it isn't very convenient.

```
let arr = struct.myArray as NSArray
var swift_arr: [UUID?] = []
for val in arr {
    if val is NSNull {
        swift_arr.append( nil )
    } else if val is NSUUID {
        swift_arr.append( val as? UUID )
    } else {
        fatalError()
    }
}
```

But if array is optional - there is big problem, because when I try to bind optional value, Swift tries to convert it to [UUID?] from NSArray, and when there is NSNull among NSUUIDs, it crashes, because NSNull cannot be converted to UUID.

Is there any proper way to handle such arrays?

Comment: You can try use `NSPointerArray`

Comment: @Cy-4AH, thanks. And is there any way to convert it to swift array without iterating over every object and without losing nils?